# Arduino Ethernet Shield - can't read file from SD card + bad working indexOf()

Tags: arduino, sd-card, ethernet

I have no idea why my sketch doesn't work correctly. I want to build a server to get analog inputs values from my Arduino (with AJAX request). I have Ethernet Shield with SD reader. On my SD card i have "index.htm" file with content of my web page (it contains HTML and JavaScript with AJAX request sending function). This is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SD.h>

// MAC address from Ethernet shield sticker under board
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,101); // IP address, may need to change depending on network
EthernetServer server(80);  // create a server at port 80

File pageFile;
String HttpReq = String();

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // initialize SD card
    Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
    if (!SD.begin(4)) {
        Serial.println("ERROR - SD card initialization failed!");
        return;    // init failed
    }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - SD card initialized.");
    // check for index.htm file
    if (!SD.exists("index.htm")) {
        Serial.println("ERROR - Can't find index.htm file!");
        return;  // can't find index file
    }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - Found index.htm fileeee.");

    pageFile = SD.open("index.htm", FILE_READ);
    if (pageFile)
    {
      Serial.println("SETUP: Reading file...");
      char c;
      while(pageFile.available())
      {
          c = pageFile.read();
          Serial.print(c);
      }
      Serial.println("SETUP: End of file reading - OK");
    } else Serial.println("SETUP: Can't read file");
    pageFile.close();

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);  // initialize Ethernet device
    server.begin();           // start to listen for clients
    Serial.print("server is at ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop()
{    
  EthernetClient client = server.available();  // try to get client   

    if (client) 
    {  // got client?
        Serial.println("New client:");    
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
        while (client.connected()) 
        {
            if (client.available()) 
            {   // client data available to read
                char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
                // last line of client request is blank and ends with \n
                // respond to client only after last line received
                HttpReq += c;
                Serial.print(c);

                if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) //end of client request, now have to send server response
                {
                    // send a standard http response header
                    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                    client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                    client.println();

                    // send web page
                    Serial.print("Position of ajax_down: ");
                    Serial.println(HttpReq.indexOf("ajax_down"));
                    if (HttpReq.indexOf("ajax_down") > -1)
                   {
                      Serial.println("!!!!! Here should be ajax_down string:");
                      Serial.println(HttpReq);
                      Serial.println("!!!!! END");

                      GetResults(client);
                   }
                   else //it wasn't ajax_down request
                   {
                      pageFile = SD.open("index.htm", FILE_READ);
                      if (pageFile)
                      {
                        Serial.println("Reading...");
                        while(pageFile.available())
                        {
                            char c = pageFile.read();
                            client.print(c);
                            Serial.print(c);                            
                        }
                        pageFile.close();
                      } 
                      else
                      {
                        Serial.println("Can't read file!");
                        client.print("Can't get results!");
                      }
                    }

                    HttpReq = "";
                    break;
                }
                // every line of text received from the client ends with \r\n
                if (c == '\n') {
                    // last character on line of received text
                    // starting new line with next character read
                    currentLineIsBlank = true;
                } 
                else if (c != '\r') {
                    // a text character was received from client
                    currentLineIsBlank = false;
                }
            } // end if (client.available())
        } // end while (client.connected())
        delay(1);      // give the web browser time to receive the data
        client.stop(); // close the connection
    } // end if (client)

}

void GetResults(EthernetClient cl)
{
  Serial.print("Getting results...");
    int temperatury = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
      temperatury += analogRead(0);
    }
    int odczytTemperatury = (temperatury/20)*(5000/1023);

    int odczytSwiatla = analogRead(5);

    cl.print(odczytTemperatury);
    cl.print(" ");
    cl.print(odczytSwiatla);
    Serial.println("OK");

}
```

In the `setup()` function I check if there is "index.htm" file on SD card and then I open it to print its content to Serial. I get the following result on COM8:

```
Initializing SD card...
SUCCESS - SD card initialized.
SUCCESS - Found index.htm fileeee.
SETUP: Reading file...
ï»¿<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Arduino odczyt</title>
</head>
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
</html>SETUP: End of file reading - OK
server is at 192.168.1.101
```

when `...` is my code. I also begin server in `setup()`. This is OK.

In `loop()` I wait for a client. If there's a client connected I read his request char by char:

```
char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
HttpReq += c;
```

When there's end of request (`if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank)`) server starts to response. First it checks if it was "ajax_down" request: `if (HttpReq.indexOf("ajax_down") > -1)` and here I have my **first problem**: When HttpReq have no "ajax_down" string it returns 0 when it should return -1 (http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringIndexOf).
COM8 output when going to 192.168.1.101 on web browser:

```
New client:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.101
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Position of ajax_down: 0
!!!!! Here should be ajax_down string:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.101
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Ge
!!!!! END
Getting results...OK
New client:
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.101
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Position of ajax_down: 0
!!!!! Here should be ajax_down string:
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.101
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-La
!!!!! END
Getting results...OK
```

It behave as if there was "ajax_down" at the begin of HttpReq, but there isn't! Then it call `GetResults(client);` so in my browser window I can see two numbers (analog input values).
But OK, let assume that it don't count from 0 but from 1, so when I change

```
if (HttpReq.indexOf("ajax_down") > -1)
```

for

```
if (HttpReq.indexOf("ajax_down") > 0)
```

It will get `else` here:

```
else //it wasn't ajax_down request
```

and there is reading a file from SD card (the same code as in `setup()`!!!) but now **I can't read the file** (but first reading at `setup()` works). 
COM8:

```
New client:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.101
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Position of ajax_down: 0
**Can't read file!**
New client:
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.101
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Position of ajax_down: 0
**Can't read file!**
```

And I get "Can't get results!" in my browser :/

I don't know why I can't open the file second time (it doesn't work also when I delete reading from `setup()`). Maybe it's caused by some memory leak? Binary size of the sketch is  24 568 bytes (max: 32 256) but I don't know if it have something to say in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm ok or not, but if you want the indexOf file declared in setup part, I think that should need to be declared in Loop as well.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

> Binary size of the sketch is 24 568 bytes (max: 32 256)
>   Maybe it's caused by some memory leak?

Are you running the code on ATMega168?
In most cases 168 can't handle SD because of its small RAM.

You should use ATMega328 (Uno) or greater to handle SD.